# jquery/javascript/unix graphing, sub categories on x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, unix

I was wondering what tool/package I can use to create a graph that can put multiple sub categories on x axis. This is very similar to a feature in excel graphs.

For example:

```
Apple| Oranges| WaterMelon | Bittermelon | Cucumbers | Lotus Root
    Fruits                 |       Vegetables
```

Answer (score 3):

[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/index.php) is a jQuery plugin that can do grouping.

This code will generate the following image:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

    var line1 = [20, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
    var xticks = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Watermelons', 'Bittermelon', 'Cucumbers', 'Lotus Root'];
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                groups: 2,
            } 
        },
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: xticks,
                rendererOptions: {
                    groupLabels:['Fruits', 'Vegetables']
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

[image]

Comment: this is awesome! how do you put more sub categories? I was thinking of adding 5 sub categories ...

Comment: The library is documented pretty well on the jqPlot site. It also comes with loads of examples when you download it. I recommend going through some of them to familiarize yourself with how it works.

Comment: Is it possible to change the size of the group? For instance, if I had 2 fruits and 4 vegetables?

Comment: @uesports135 I haven't used this library in years so I can't answer that. You may want to ask a new question instead of asking in a comment.