# Is it possible to have differently sized subgroups in jqplot?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

The example given as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444167/jquery-javascript-unix-graphing-sub-categories-on-x-axis) shows how to create two different subgroups on the x-axis using jqplot, but is there an approach that would work if I had only two vegetables but three fruits (or more generally >1 differently sized subgroups)?